# displaying multiple array variables

Tags: java, arrays, loops, delimiter

This program gets user input for 2 teams and 2 results, separates them with the " : " delimiter, then stores them in the array, when the user enters the word "stop" it stops asking for user input and is meant to display the results and stats of the match (which is not yet added into the code). the problem I'm having is if I type more than one line of match results then type 'stop', it only displays the first line of user input back to the console and not any of the others? input example: "Chelsea : Arsenal : 2 : 1".

```
public static final String SENTINEL = "stop";

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String hometeam = new String();
    String awayteam = new String();
    String homescore = new String();
    String awayscore = new String();

    int result0;
    int result1;

    System.out.println("please enter match results:");

    // loop, wil ask for match results ( b < () )
    for (int b = 0; b < 100; b++) {

        String s = sc.nextLine();

        // stop command
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) { // better than the for loop

            String line = sc.nextLine();

            String results[] = s.split(" : "); // parse strings in between
                                                // the

            for (String temp : results) {
                hometeam = results[0];
                awayteam = results[1];
                homescore = results[2];
                awayscore = results[3];
            }

            // convert 'score' strings to int value.
            result0 = Integer.valueOf(results[2]);
            result1 = Integer.valueOf(results[3]);

            if ("stop".equals(line)) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
                return; // exit
            }
```

Comment: You are declaring and initializing **results** on every iteration of **while** statement, so it is always different.

Comment: Why `for (String temp : results) {`?

Comment: I got that from a different stackoverflow question and it worked so I just left it in

Comment: You probably took it out of context. If you just copy/paste code without understanding it, you'll never learn to code by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it outputs the first results you entered is because `results` is assigned to `s.split(" : ")`. `s` never changes in the first iteration of the outer for loop, so `s.split(" : ")` never changes. Your `results` always holds the first match results!

You have written your code very wrongly.

First, why do you have a while loop inside a for loop? The for loop is redundant.

Second, you can't use arrays for this. Try an `ArrayList`. Arrays don't have the ability to change its size dynamically.

Third, I recommend you to create a class for this, to represent a `MatchResult`.

```
class MatchResult {
    private String homeTeam;
    private String awayTeam;
    private int homeScore;
    private int awayScore;

    public String getHomeTeam() {
        return homeTeam;
    }

    public String getAwayTeam() {
        return awayTeam;
    }

    public int getHomeScore() {
        return homeScore;
    }

    public int getAwayScore() {
        return awayScore;
    }

    public MatchResult(String homeTeam, String awayTeam, int homeScore, int awayScore) {
        this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
        this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
        this.homeScore = homeScore;
        this.awayScore = awayScore;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MatchResult{" +
            "homeTeam='" + homeTeam + '\'' +
            ", awayTeam='" + awayTeam + '\'' +
            ", homeScore=" + homeScore +
            ", awayScore=" + awayScore +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Then, you can create an `ArrayList<MatchResult>` that stores the user input.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String hometeam;
String awayteam;
int homescore;
int awayscore;
ArrayList<MatchResult> list = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.println("please enter match results:");
while (sc.hasNextLine()) { // better than the for loop

    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if ("stop".equals(line)) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
        return; // exit
    }
    String results[] = line.split(" : "); // parse strings in between

    hometeam = results[0];
    awayteam = results[1];
    homescore = Integer.valueOf(results[2]);
    awayscore = Integer.valueOf(results[3]);

    list.add(new MatchResult(hometeam, awayteam, homescore, awayscore));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try just adding another array

```
string[] matches = new string[]{};
```

then input your values into the array. I am using b since that is the int variable in your loop. I also put in + " : "

```
matches [b] = hometeam.tostring() + " : " + awayteam.tostring() + homescore.tostring() + " : " + awayscore.tostring();
```

then change the print to

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matches));
```

i think this should work, but I wasn't able to test it.

```
public static final String SENTINEL = "stop";

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    string[] matches = new string[]{};
    String hometeam = new String();
    String awayteam = new String();
    String homescore = new String();
    String awayscore = new String();

    int result0;
    int result1;

    System.out.println("please enter match results:");

    // loop, wil ask for match results ( b < () )
    for (int b = 0; b < 100; b++) {

        String s = sc.nextLine();

        // stop command
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) { // better than the for loop

            String line = sc.nextLine();

            String results[] = s.split(" : "); // parse strings in between
                                                // the

            for (String temp : results) {
                hometeam = results[0];
                awayteam = results[1];
                homescore = results[2];
                awayscore = results[3];
            }

            // convert 'score' strings to int value.
            result0 = Integer.valueOf(results[2]);
            result1 = Integer.valueOf(results[3]);

            matches [b] = hometeam.tostring() + " : " + awayteam.tostring() + homescore.tostring() + " : " + awayscore.tostring();

            if ("stop".equals(line)) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matches));
                return; // exit
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple loop to grab all data from user until "stop" is entered and display the output of the input

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String[]> stats = new ArrayList<>(); //initialize a container to hold all the stats
    System.out.println("please enter match results:");
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        String[] results = input.split(" : ");
        if(results.length == 4)
        {
            stats.add(results);
        }
        else if(input.equals("stop"))
            break;
        else
            System.out.println("Error reading input");
    }//end of while

    for(int i = 0; i < stats.size(); i++)
    {
        try{
            System.out.println(stats.get(i)[0] + " vs " + stats.get(i)[1] + " : " +
                Integer.valueOf(stats.get(i)[2]) + " - " + Integer.valueOf(stats.get(i)[3]));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            //do nothing with any invalid input
        }
    }
```

Output

```
please enter match results:
r : b : 5 : 4
r : c : 7 : 10
j : g : 3 : 9
stop
r vs b : 5 - 4
r vs c : 7 - 10
j vs g : 3 - 9
```